# Finding adjacent values count in a list

Tags: python, list, function, loops, oop

The given code is supposed to show the count of equal adjacent values of the given list

```
def get_count(num_list):
    count=0
    
    for i in num_list:
        j=1
        if i == num_list[j]:
           print(i , j)
           j+1
        

    # Write your logic here

    return count

#provide different values in list and test your program
num_list=[10,10,30,40,20,20]
print(get_count())
```

For example in the above input the value 10 and 20 are equal to its adjacent value so the expected output is to be 2.

**I couldn't find the logic error done here**
*Thanks for helping in Advance*

Comment: You need to write `j = j + 1` or `j += 1`.  What you have just adds 1 to j, and then throws the result away.  Your code is also going to fail when looking at the last element, because num_list[j] is going to give you an array index out of bounds exception.

Comment: For a new programmer, it might be easier if you just have a for loop that increments `index` from 0 to `len(num_list) - 1)`, then then compares `num_list[index]` to `num_list[index + 1]. `

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing 'j' value inside the if condition. So everytime it won't get updated and you don't get the count value as expected.Also I hope you are trying to increment j.But you should do j+=1 or j=j+1.
Instead you can try like this:

```
    def get_count(num_list):
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(num_list)-1):
            if(num_list[i] == num_list[i+1]):
                count+=1
        return count
    lis = [10,10,20,30,30,40,50,50]
    print(get_count(lis))
```